# Why is "yield" keyword not producing the expected generator in my application? (Merge sort algorithm)

Tags: python, algorithm, generator, mergesort, yield

Why is my `yield` keyword not yielding the expected output?

I'm working with a recursive algorithm (Merge-sort) and using `yield` so that I can iterate through the list every time it's changed (sorted).

```
def MergeSort(lst):

    if len(lst) > 1:
        middle = len(lst)//2
        lefthalf = lst[:middle]
        righthalf = lst[middle:]

        MergeSort(lefthalf)
        MergeSort(righthalf)

        i,j,k= 0,0,0

        while i<len(lefthalf) and j<len(righthalf):
            if lefthalf[i] < righthalf[j]:
                lst[k] = lefthalf[i]
                i+=1
            else:
                lst[k] = righthalf[j]
                j+=1

            k+=1

        while i<len(lefthalf):
            lst[k]=lefthalf[i]
            i+=1
            k+=1

        while j<len(righthalf):
            lst[k]=righthalf[j]
            j+=1
            k+=1

        yield lst
```

```
a = MergeSort([2,3,566,78,8])
for i in a:
    print(i)
[2, 3, 566, 78, 8]
```

Instead, I hope to achieve something like: (as the algorithm works)

```
[2, 3, 566, 78, 8]
[2, 3, 566, 8, 78]
[2, 3, 8, 78, 566]
```

If I use a `return` statement it will work and sort the list as expected, but when I use `yield` I can't get a proper generator. I also tried placing the `yield` inside the `while` statements and everywhere else pretty much. How can I fix this? What am I missing?

Comment: Each time you call `MergeSort`, it is only aware of the part of the list it is currently sorting, so it can't provide you a 'view' of the complete list.

Comment: Why are you using `yield`for this?

Comment: I'd like to create an animated bar chart using the generator `yield` outputs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you made `MergeSort` a generator, and generators are lazy, your recursive calls don't actually do any sorting; they just return generators which won't do any work until you iterate through them. Your whole function also yields only one list because it only contains one `yield` statement, and this is not in a loop so it is only executed once.

The fix to both of these is to use `yield from MergeSort(...)` to exhaust the generators you recursively created. This will exhaust them so that they do the sorting work, and also cause the outer generator to yield whatever the inner generators yield. So, change these two lines:

```py
        yield from MergeSort(lefthalf)
        yield from MergeSort(righthalf)
```

Example:

```py
>>> for i in MergeSort([2, 3, 566, 78, 8]):
...     print(i)
... 
[2, 3]
[8, 78]
[8, 78, 566]
[2, 3, 8, 78, 566]
```

Note that you aren't seeing lists of the same length; the recursive calls are on shorter lists, so they yield shorter lists. You also aren't seeing the lists of length 1 in the base case, because your `yield lst` statement is inside the `if len(lst) > 1:` block. If you un-indent that line so that `yield lst` is unconditional, you can see the result of every call:

```py
>>> for i in MergeSort([2, 3, 566, 78, 8]):
...     print(i)
... 
[2]
[3]
[2, 3]
[566]
[78]
[8]
[8, 78]
[8, 78, 566]
[2, 3, 8, 78, 566]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me understand this. Your explanation was perfect and using yield from solved the issue. Very useful, thanks again!